# How to add behaviour (onclick) on <span> in a <tr> tag which has different behaviour (onclick)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a data `table` which has a `span` element in every row. When someone clicks on the `<tr>` element JS code is executed. When someone clicks on the `<span>` element another JS code is execute.
The problem is that often it detects the click on the `<tr>` even though I click on the `<span>` element.

Is there any javascript/jquery function which helps me out?

HTML Code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="behaviourTr">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS Code

```
$('.behaviourTr').on('click', function() { ... });
$('.glyphicon-pencil').on('click', function() { ... });
```

Comment: The click event on the span element is bubbling up to the tr element. You need to cancel the event within the span element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the `span` element, you are technically still clicking on the `tr` element as well (because the `span` is a descendant element and the event bubbles up to the `tr` element).

Inside of the `tr` click event listener, you could check `event.target` (which is the clicked element) to see if the `span` element wasn't clicked. In the snippet below, the `is()` method is used to determine if `event.target` is *not* a `span` element.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/e9vmwytw/).

```
$('.behaviourTr').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('span')) {
    // The tr was clicked, but the span wasn't
  }
});
```

Comment: Understandable explanation and working solution! Thank you, sir! :)

Answer (score 0):

Within the callback function, you need to check for the element that is actually caused the event.  I bet you'll need one click event for your multiple elements.

I'm on my phone, so hopefully this makes sense...

```
$('.behaviourTr').on('click', function(e) {
 var targetElm = $(e.currentTarget);

If(targetElm.is('.glyphicon-pencil')){
//the pencil was clicked
}

If(targetElm.is('.behaviourTr')){
//the tr was clicked
}

});
```

e.target == element listening for event

e.currentTarget == element that triggered event

Answer (score 0):

It is called [event propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) which is very classic in js.

Actually, there is another method through stop propagation, not through detect the target.

Demo is here.http://jsbin.com/sufede/edit?html,css,js,output